# How to remove spaces in front of punctuation

Tags: vba, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a string which contains punctuation. With every piece of punctuation there is a space in front of it.

For example, **`"Do you like ?"`**.

How would I delete spaces in front of every piece of punctuation?

Comment: what have you done so far? :)

Comment: You can use regex

Comment: You can easily solve this with regex, you should learn it

Comment: what's your environment, actually? VBA is not compatible with Visual Studio. Please edit the tags consistently with your issue and you may also want to specify which application you're targeting (Word, Excel, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression like " +([\?!,.])"` to replace every ? ! , or . preceded by at least one space :

```
Dim regEx As New RegExp
With regEx
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .Pattern = " +([\?!,\.])"
End With

Dim strInput As String: strInput = "Do you like it  , really ? Yeah ! Not kidding  ? Cool ."
strInput = regEx.Replace(strInput, "$1")
MsgBox strInput
```

You need to add a reference to **Microsoft VBScript Regular Expression 5.5** in Tools/References menu of your VBA editor (I used Word 2013 VBA editor for this example)

Comment: Sweet I'll try it once I get home :) I saw that one before but I didn't know you had to reference the VB stuff in the editor so that's probably why it didn't work.